# How does requestConnection for PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager work in Apache HttpAsyncClient?

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpasyncclient

How does requestConnection for PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager work in Apache HttpAsyncClient? Can someone show me a working example?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it is being used inside `HttpAsyncClient`

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.1.x/httpasyncclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/nio/client/AbstractClientExchangeHandler.html

Is there any particular reason you want to use `PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager` directly instead of using it through `HttpAsyncClient`?

Comment: Yes, it should. Alternatively one can request, say, 5 connections from the pool and immediately release all of them back to the pool. That'll ensure there are 5 warm connections in the pool.

Comment: Only by sending a heart-beat message every once in a while. If you can give up proxy support, complex auth schemes and state management you might consider using BasicNIOConnPool. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.4.x/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpClient.java. It offers a simpler API than PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.

Comment: You need to start the i/o reactor